# Multi-select list box in an excel spreadsheet using data validation

Tags: c#, excel, listbox, multi-select, closedxml

I want to achieve a multi-select list box in an excel spreadsheet using data validation.

I found a link [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-list-box-or-combo-box-to-a-worksheet-in-Excel-579e1958-f7f6-41ae-ba0c-c83cc6e40878) which talks about developer tab in MS-excel where I can drag and drop a list box control to achieve the list box effect. Possibly that is the Visual Studio tools for Office (VSTO) route. I do not want to go this route.

Instead, I'm trying to achieve it through data validation and [ClosedXML](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML/) nuget package.

I already have below code with the help of which I can create a drop down but not sure how can I convert it into a multi-select list box:

```
//imported namespaces
using ClosedXML.Excel;
using System;
using System.Data;

//code in main method
var workbook = new XLWorkbook();

DataTable userData = new DataTable("Sheet1");
userData.Columns.Add("Master Column");


workbook.AddWorksheet(userData);
var worksheet = workbook.Worksheet(1);


 DataTable validationTable = new DataTable();
 validationTable.Columns.Add("DropDownItems");
 validationTable.TableName = "Sheet2";

 DataRow dr = validationTable.NewRow();
 dr["DropDownItems"] = "Item1";
 validationTable.Rows.Add(dr);

 dr = validationTable.NewRow();
 dr["DropDownItems"] = "Item2";
 validationTable.Rows.Add(dr);

 dr = validationTable.NewRow();
 dr["DropDownItems"] = "Item3";
 validationTable.Rows.Add(dr);


 workbook.AddWorksheet(validationTable);
 var worksheet2 = workbook.Worksheet(2);
 worksheet.Column(1).SetDataValidation().List(worksheet2.Range("A2:A4"), true);

  //keep the data validation worksheet hidden
  worksheet2.Hide();

  workbook.SaveAs(@"C:\myworkbook.xlsx");
```

Currently this source code results in a combo box like this:

[image]

I've to achieve multi-select behavior programatically using ClosedXML in C#.

Comment: With ClosedXML, you can load existing Files from Disk and examine them. I'd suggest to manually create such an Excel Document containing this control, then load it in ClosedXML and Debug the contents of the specific cell/range. Interesting to see what you get.

Comment: @RBT  Did you found any solution then please let me know. I am also on same page and I am trying to achieve this functionality using OpenXML nuget package.

Answer (score 1):

The Developer Tab doesn't require Visual Studio; it's just hidden away.

- Go `File` → `Options` → on the left: `Customize Ribbon`.
- Click on the `Developer` *checkbox* under the list of `Main Tabs` on the right.
- Click `OK`.

[image: Developer Options]

A new 'menu' will appear on the ribbon called `Developer`, with categories like Code, Add-Ins, Controls, XML, Modify (varying depending on your version).

In Excel, you can't readily "convert" controls from one type to another like in Access etc, but with the Developers menu visible, you can now create a Listbox, and copy the VBA over from your Combo Box.

[image: Developer Toolbar2]

If you give the Listbox the same name the Combo Box had (after you delete the Combo Box) then the transition will be even easier.  (If not there's always <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> Search & Replace!)

Comment: I'm trying to achieve it through data validation and ClosedXML nuget package.

Answer (score 0):

Form controls are not supported by ClosedXML.

Comment: Yes. I want to achieve it through data validation route. Is it possible to achieve it through data validation. Through data validation I'm able to create a single select drop down box. Can I tweak the code I've shown so that it becomes multi-select?